# Networking not working on ubuntu server 12.10 on B75MA-P45 mobo

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet

Just got some new parts to but together a local development server with Ubuntu server 12.10 and I can't get networking working.

I have an airport extreme for my router and it works find with CentOS boxes I have running now. it uses DHCP.

I have tried using auto and static configurations in `/etc/network/interfaces` with no luck

I also followed this guide to install the rtl8168 driver http://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/

`ping 8.8.8.8` gives the error "Network is unreachable"

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr ***
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB) TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
        ....
```

removed HWadder and left the Local loopback in the above output

I tried changing ethernet cables

This is a new install on a new box, it was never able to connect to the internet, even during initial install and after a reinstall

I am using the B75MA-P45 motherboard from MSI. I also have a PWLA8391GT pci adapter if that would help. I have tried without the adapter installed.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

After fixing the issue with the driver my ethernet card is now working so I can ssh to the server. But I would like to get the tcp on the actual motherboard working. this is the current output of `ifconfig -a`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr *** 
          inet addr:10.0.1.99  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92e2:baff:fe39:5c9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:160632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:84432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:214002238 (214.0 MB)  TX bytes:11277417 (11.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20610 (20.6 KB)  TX bytes:20610 (20.6 KB)

p1p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ***  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0xc000 

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr *** 
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

What is `p1p1` and `virbr0`? How do i use them/configure them so that I can use the other tcp port?

Comment: Is the module loaded? Check `lspci -v`.

Comment: interesting, it still says it uses r8169 but also lists the r8168 module

Comment: You need to blacklist the r8169 module, and also unload it. Did you do step 7?

Comment: Yea, I think i fixed it though, I got some errors on the mkinitramfs step a while back and disregarded it then but went back now, it seems it used uname as a string since `uname -r` is written as 'uname -r'

Comment: Now it is using the r8168 driver but it didn't change anything for me, still no working networking.

Comment: If you followed all the steps in the guide, I suggest looking at the logs to see what the driver is doing if anything. A reasonable place to start is `/var/log/kern.log` or your distribution's equivalent. `messages` and `syslog` are also reasonable places to look.

Comment: my network card is now working, the PWLA8391GT adapter. But the setup I want to use requires two tcp ports so I would really like to get the motherboard port working. I will check the logs shortly.

Comment: I have looked through kern.log and messages but did not find any errors or anything related to the networking issue. However I may have missed something since I am not used to troubleshooting networking errors, I use these servers for web development. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: I'm unclear what you are trying to do. Is there a second ethernet card you want to get working? I'm not sure what you mean by "tcp on the actual motherboard", for example. Disclaimer: my knowledge of networking is  negligible. Also, when the ethernet driver/module is loaded/started, there really should be some messages about it in your logs.

Answer (score 0):

p1p0 is a interface wich name was given by BIOS. More information at :

http://linux.die.net/man/1/biosdevname

and the vibr0 it's a virtual bridge. More information at :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/246343/what-is-the-virbr0-interface-used-for